# Call back to Application Controller error - NameError (undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm upgrading an application from Rails 2 to 3. I use a Rights and Role approach for authentication that worked fine under Rails 2. In my Application Controller (application.rb) I have:

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

```
def check_authentication
    unless session[:user]
            session[:intended_resource] = request.request_uri
            session[:intended_action] = action_name
            session[:intended_controller] = controller_name
            redirect_to :controller => "sessions", :action => "new"
            return false
     end
 end

 def check_authorization
   user = User.find(session[:user])
   unless user.roles.detect{|role|
     role.rights.detect{|right|
       right.action == action_name && right.controller == self.class.controller_path
       }
     }
     flash[:notice] = "You are not authorized to view the page you requested"
     request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] ? (redirect_to :back) : (redirect_to :controller => "sessions", :action => "new")
     return false
   end
 end
```

end

In my other controllers I've included a before filter.

```
   before_filter :check_authentication,:check_authorization
```

I'm getting the following error message, for example, when I go to my Dashboard Controller.

```
  NameError (undefined local variable or method `check_authentication' for DashboardController:0x0000010291a0c0):
```

Is there something else I need to change or add to make this work in Rails 3?

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: Anukul, I checked that and it was okay.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your DashboardController is inheriting from ApplicationController i.e. `DashboardController < ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Somehow during my upgrade I had a file named application.rb and application_controller.rb in my controllers folder. Both were defined as ApplicationController < ActionController::Base. The code for my "real" Application Controller was sitting in application.rb and not in application_controller.rb, which was empty. A simple copy-n-paste and things were fine. I don't know how that happened. Running the rails_upgrade plugin didn't go as smoothly as planned.